# Updating a column with time difference between current time and a record in same table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to update a column with time difference between current time and a record in same table.

Actually in this table column `To` should be `NOW()` and `Diffs` should be the difference between `From` and `To`:

```
| ID |       Froms      |    To    |     Diffs  |
+----+------------------+----------+------------+
| 1  |  15:15:59.00000  |   NULL   |     NULL   |
+----+------------------+----------+------------+
```

When I tried this query, I got a bunch of errors:

```
UPDATE dailyHours 
SET Diffs = (SELECT TIMEDIFF(TIME(NOW()), (SELECT Froms FROM dailyHours WHERE To is NULL)))
WHERE To IS NULL
```

Comment: I advise you to avoid reserved words like `TO` , which can be replaced with other english words like `UNTIL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a subquery?

If that is the logic you want, then:

```
update dailyHours
   set Diffs = timediff(time(now()), Froms)
   where `to` is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign `NOW()` to a variable then update the `time` with variable:

```
update_time=now()
```

now update like this:

```
UPDATE dailyHours SET Diffs = timed(update_time,Forms) WHERE `To` is NULL;
```

I hope to help you.